# What is the grammatical name of the part of the sentence that is in bold?

Tags: grammar

1. **SEWING** the cassock,John pricked his finger.
2. Mercy and Mary like **smiling**.
3. The Municipal Assembly has a **towing** car.
4. The boys are **playing** their roles well.

Comment: There are four sentences. And more than one part of speech. But they're all -ing forms.

Answer (score 1):

1. Present participle - short for 'Whilst sewing...
2. Gerund noun - direct object of the verb.
3. Gerund noun used as adjective.
4. Present continuous tense of verb 'play'.

Comment: +1 but I would add 1. ... used as an adjectival phrase; and 4. *playing* is a present participle use to form the present continuous.